# Facebook showing error: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: php, facebook

I tried to integrate Facebook post on user timeline. For this I am using facebook php sdk. I have created app ID and put all valid values which require on integration.

[image]

As it is showing the domain of this URL is not included in the app's domains but I have entered right URL.

Answer (score 0):

In settings of you facebook application, you need to provide a domain, not url.

For example, if your authentication is performed on https://example.org/auth/facebook, you need to provide domain `example.org` in settings